# Removing Code Behind from a deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a site that I'm about to publish and I want to know how to set it so it would not deploy the code behind?

Essentially i'm trying to find the difference between an aspx file that calls the code behind .cs file and another that calls a dll that's in the BIN directory?

Comment: These are few links which might help you..http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/article.php/c19419/Deploying-ASPNET-Applications--Part-1.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143274/how-do-you-deploy-your-asp-net-applications-to-live-servers

Answer (score 0):

The below explanation from the Microsoft [ASP.NET documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/8/9/E8920AE6-D441-41A7-8A77-9EF8FF970D8B/aspnet_tutorial02_FilesToDeploy_cs.pdf) discusses  the difference between explicit and automatic compilation.

> In order for the ASP.NET engine to service a request for this page,
>   the page's code portion (the WebPage.aspx.cs file) must first be
>   compiled. This compilation can happen explicitly or automatically.
>
> With **explicit compilation** you need to copy up the assemblies in the
>   Bin folder, but you do not need to copy up the ASP.NET pages' code
>   portions (the WebPage.aspx.cs files).
>
> With **automatic compilation** you need to copy up the code portion files
>   so that the code is present and can be compiled automatically when the
>   page is visited.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish a web project (from Visual Studio), the source code from code behind (.aspx.cs files) will be converted to a binary dll file named as [YourWebProject].dll and will be copied under the "bin" folder.